# Why can 4 bits store values in the range 0-15?

Tags: c, bit

```
struct bitCard {
   unsigned int face : 4;
   unsigned int suit : 2;
   unsigned int color : 1;
};
```

"The preceding structure definition indicates that member face is stored in 4 bits,
member suit is stored in 2 bits and member color is stored in 1 bit. The number of bits is based on the desired range of values for each structure member. **Member face stores
values from 0(Ace) through 12(King)—4 bits can store values in the range 0–15.**" (C how to program). 
The sentence in bold makes me confused since I cannot help myself understand why 4 bits can store values from 0 to 15. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Binary `0000` = decimal 0, binary `1111` = decimal 15. Stored right ? Read more about binary number systems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think 2 in the power of 4 = 16 possible values...
binary value represent decimal number in range 0..2^x - where X=num of bits

Answer (score 1):

because `15 = 1 * 2^3 + 1 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 1*2^0` ie: `15 = 0xF = 1111b`

Where `^` is the power operation.

Or, more detailed:

```
0000 = 0
0001 = 1
0010 = 2
0011 = 3
0100 = 4
0101 = 5
0110 = 6
0111 = 7
1000 = 8
1001 = 9
1010 = 10
1011 = 11
1100 = 12
1101 = 13
1110 = 14
1111 = 15
```

I really can recommend reading the wikipedia article about binary numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Answer (score 1):

Because 1+2+4+8 = 15 it follows that 4-digit binary numbers can range from 0 to 15. The numbers are:

```
0000b =  0d
0001b =  1d
0010b =  2d
0011b =  3d
...
1110b = 14d
1111b = 15d
```

Answer (score 1):

as there only `16` unique combinations (thanks Udo) of `0`,`1` that you can represent with 4 bits

```
 0000  0
 0001  1 
 0010  2 
 0011  3
.........
 1111  15
```

Comment: These are not Permutation but Combinations.

Comment: @UdoKlein definitely, fixed